# VBA-Iterating through worksheets and finding occurrences of values, make it more efficient

Tags: vba, excel

I am iterating through a workbook and searching how many times are person1 and val1 in the same row and then adding 1 to a specified cell for each time this happens. The only way I could make this work was by copying and pasting the following code for each individual person. This becomes too inefficient for many people and excel will not run it, any recommendations as how I can avoid mass copying and pasting?

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ws As Worksheets 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
    'Set MyRng =
    ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 4

    For I = 1 To ws_num
        ind = 9
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
        Do While ind <= 39


            If Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val1" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val2" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("B7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("B7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val3" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("D7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("D7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val4" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("E7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("E7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val5" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("F7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("F7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val6" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("G7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("G7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val7" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("H7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("H7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val8" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("I7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("I7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val9" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("J7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("J7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val10" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("K7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("K7").Value + 1
            ElseIf Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "val11" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("L7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("L7").Value + 1



            End If
            ind = ind + 1
        Loop


    Next
```

Comment: One option would be to use the Case method here for your val1-11. Load your persons into an array and then iterate through `LBOUND` and `UBOUND`?

Comment: You need to place the people and values into arrays, then iterate through those - that would improve readability and save you space, but it shouldn't change how your code runs - I think that issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: I looked in to case method and I am unsure how that would work in my scenario because i am iterating through several workbooks

Comment: Although readability it important, my main concern in efficiency and creating DRY code

Comment: Put these statements at beginning and ending of your code:
 `Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` 
Then removes at the end of your code.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with you could use:

```
If Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "person1" Then
```

To only evaluate that once. then use

```
Select Case Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value
    Case "val1" 
        Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value + 1
    Case "val2"
        Worksheets("scrap").Range("B7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("B7").Value + 1
```

And so on

As clarified by urdearboy, the above should be in the loop, replacing all those `If...Elseifs`

Comment: House this code inside a loop for an array containing each indv you want to test for (suggestion for OP)

Comment: I would go as far as to create a string variable called `Rng` and have the `Case` statement look like: `Case "val1"  Rng = "C7"`. Then you can move the entire `Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value + 1` outside the Case statement and make it something along the lines of `Worksheets("scrap").Range(Rng).Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range(Rng).Value + 1`... Would just make for cleaner code, but I like your idea.

Comment: @urdearboy, I'm not seeing you doing what I mentioned... Not to say you have to, but just saying I'm not seeing it....

Comment: I was just saying that I agree that it *should* be done ;) DO IT! I built off cyber so its not like I can complain if you build off mine lulz

Answer (score 1):

Building on cybernetic.nomads solution, you can house your Case inside a loop of your array `Persons`. You will need to update this array with all values you want to loop through of course.

Dimmed your "Scrap" worksheet for aesthetic reasons.
Removed `.Value` where possible.
Turn off `ScreenUpdating` for good measure to spare memory.

```
Sub Main()

Dim ws As Worksheets 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 4

Dim Scrap As Worksheet
Set Scrap = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scrap")

Dim P As Integer
Dim Persons As Variant
Persons = Array("person1", "person2", "person3", "personN")        

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For P = LBound(Persons) To UBound(perons)
    For I = 1 To ws_num
    ind = 9
        Do While ind <= 39
            If Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = Persons(P) Then
                Select Case Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind.Value)
                    Case "val1"
                        Scrap.Range("C7") = Scrap.Range("C7").Value + 1
                    Case "val2"
                        Scrap.Range("B7") = Scrap.Range("B7").Value + 1
                    Case "val3"
                         Scrap.Range("D7") = Scrap.Range("D7").Value + 1
                    Case "val4"
                         Scrap.Range("E7") = Scrap.Range("E7").Value + 1
                    Case "val5"
                         Scrap.Range("F7") = Scrap.Range("F7").Value + 1
                    Case "val6"
                         Scrap.Range("G7") = Scrap.Range("G7").Value + 1
                    Case "val7"
                         Scrap.Range("H7") = Scrap.Range("H7").Value + 1
                    Case "val8"
                         Scrap.Range("I7") = Scrap.Range("I7").Value + 1
                    Case "val9"
                         Scrap.Range("J7") = Scrap.Range("J7").Value + 1
                    Case "val0"
                         Scrap.Range("J7") = Scrap.Range("K7").Value + 1
                    Case "val11"
                         Scrap.Range("L7") = Scrap.Range("L7").Value + 1
                End Select
            End If
        ind = ind + 1
        Loop
    Next I
Next P

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```